# Generate a new group ID every time a variable changes its value

Tags: r, grouping

Have been searching for a while, but haven't found what I wanted. For the sake of exposition, suppose one has a data set like the following:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(666)
foo = data.table(id = 1:20, value = sample(c(1, -1), 20, replace = T))
    id value
 1:  1    -1
 2:  2     1
 3:  3    -1
 4:  4     1
 5:  5     1
 6:  6    -1
 7:  7    -1
 8:  8     1
 9:  9     1
10: 10     1
11: 11    -1
12: 12     1
13: 13     1
14: 14     1
15: 15     1
16: 16    -1
17: 17     1
18: 18    -1
19: 19     1
20: 20     1
```

I want to create a unique group id every time `value` changes, resulting in

```
    id value grp
 1:  1    -1   1
 2:  2     1   2
 3:  3    -1   3
 4:  4     1   4
 5:  5     1   4
 6:  6    -1   5
 7:  7    -1   5
 8:  8     1   6
 9:  9     1   6
10: 10     1   6
11: 11    -1   7
12: 12     1   8
13: 13     1   8
14: 14     1   8
15: 15     1   8
16: 16    -1   9
17: 17     1  10
18: 18    -1  11
19: 19     1  12
20: 20     1  12
```

I can do it in a loop

```
foo[, cc := value == shift(value)][is.na(cc), cc := FALSE]

for(i in 1:nrow(foo)){
  if(foo[i]$cc != T){ 
    pp = i
    foo[i, grp := pp]} else {
      foo[i, grp := pp]}
}

foo[, grp := as.numeric(as.factor(grp))]
```

Is there a smarter way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rleid`

```
foo[, grp := rleid(value)]
foo
#    id value grp
# 1:  1    -1   1
# 2:  2     1   2
# 3:  3    -1   3
# 4:  4     1   4
# 5:  5     1   4
# 6:  6    -1   5
# 7:  7    -1   5
# 8:  8     1   6
# 9:  9     1   6
#10: 10     1   6
#11: 11    -1   7
#12: 12     1   8
#13: 13     1   8
#14: 14     1   8
#15: 15     1   8
#16: 16    -1   9
#17: 17     1  10
#18: 18    -1  11
#19: 19     1  12
#20: 20     1  12
```